# Custom classes and usage throughout programs

Tags: c#, oop

Say I have a custom data class.  It just holds data in a meaningful way.

The class might look like:

```
class MyClass
{
    public struct MyType
    {
        public string parameter;
        public string data;
        public string value;
    }

    public List<MyType> myTypeList= new List<MyType>();
}
```

Say I have a program that creates many of these classes.  The data is filled from parsing a number of files and the `List<MyType>` will have an indefinite number of items when done grabbing data.  I then use this data in several ways throughout the program (Create documents, display on GUI, etc...).

When I add to the list in my Parsing class, I must first create a new object of `MyType` and then add it to `myTypeList`.  So the parsing class has to actually know of and use the inner object type.  Once it is added, though, I can just use an instance of `MyClass` to access the fields directly without any knowledge of type.

Such as:

```
string myString = myClassInstance.myTypeList[0].parameter;
```

Is it better to create a method inside the `MyClass` that lets the parsing class pass in data without knowledge of the underlying type?  If so, what is the best way of doing this?

I can think of several ways to do it, I just don't know if it's the best or correct way.  I guess it would better generalize the code, but could be less readable when adding data.

Edit: Adding in usage differences due to comment.

```
class MyParser
{
    public List<MyClass> ParseFile(string[] lines)
    {
        List<MyClass> myClassInstance = new MyClass();
        foreach(string line in lines)
        {
            MyType typeInstance = new MyType();
            typeInstance.parameter = line.Substring(0, 1);
            typeInstance.data = line.Substring(1, 1);
            typeInstance.value = line.Substring(2, 1);
            myClassInstance.myTypeList.Add(typeInstance);                
        }
    }
 }
```

Vs. Something like:

```
class MyParser
{
    public List<MyClass> ParseFile(string[] lines)
    {
        List<MyClass> myClassInstance = new MyClass();
        foreach(string line in lines)
        {
             myClassInstance.AddData(line.Substring(0, 1), 
                                     line.Substring(1, 1), 
                                     line.Substring(2, 1));                                
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: it's really not clear to me what you're asking or what your specific use case is.  Perhaps some sample of your parsing code or a better explanation of your issue?

Comment: Added in one type of usage I might envision.  There are probably better ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's best to keep the `MyType` class separate. It has one purpose, to represent whatever it represents. If it does that then it's perfect and doesn't need to change. (Look at the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).)

In most cases it makes sense to do exactly what you're doing. Another class has its own responsibility, to take some input - a file, the results of a SQL query, etc., and read it into a class or collection of classes.

Sometimes if it gets complicated it's good to break it down even further - perhaps one class reads from a file and other converts a record from the file into a class. But that's often overkill. At most it's usually enough to break those up into separate methods in one class.

The only case I can think of where a class "owns" the function of parsing something is with value types like `int` or `DateTime` or classes like `IpAddress` where string representations are so common that it makes sense to have methods like `int.Parse(string)` or `DateTime.Parse(string)`. But that wouldn't make sense for something more complex like parsing a record from a file or a SQL record.

Comment: I guess I'm more talking about hiding the inner struct type from other classes.  The class itself isn't parsing the data, just controlling how it's added.  I apologize for the vague question.

Comment: If the struct is only meant to be used within the other class then I wouldn't expose it. Other classes don't need to know whether that class stores its member variables separately or in a struct. If you want to use the struct to group those values instead of passing them separately then I would move that struct outside of the other class. Someone could get confused and wonder why that struct is declared inside the other class.